# is there a way to solve heroku 503 deploying error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I would like to thank you guys in advance. so I am having issues opening my express server after I have deployed it on Heroku. The issue is I keep on getting the error below and I hope someone can please help me.

2023-02-06T09:34:31.419072+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2023-02-06T09:34:31.419234+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2023-02-06T09:34:31.419978+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2023-02-06T09:34:31.420062+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2023-02-06T09:34:31.420152+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2023-02-06T09:34:31.420229+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 start script.
2023-02-06T09:34:31.420301+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2023-02-06T09:34:31.428635+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-02-06T09:34:31.428714+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2023-02-06T09:34:31.428770+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2023-02-06T09_34_31_420Z-debug.log
2023-02-06T09:34:31.607388+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-02-06T09:34:31.670514+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-02-06T09:34:57.360088+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=thewrightlogistic.herokuapp.com request_id=45a256da-ca0f-4af1-86a6-a7fc81112803 fwd="98.174.153.51" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-02-06T09:34:57.360088+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=thewrightlogistic.herokuapp.com request_id=45a256da-ca0f-4af1-86a6-a7fc81112803 fwd="98.174.153.51" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('./database')
const middleware = require('./middleware')
const cors = require('cors')


const app = express();

const contactRouter = require('./routes/contactRoutes');
const authRouter = require('./routes/authRoutes');
const userRouter = require('./routes/userRoutes');
// const dashboardRouter = require('./routes/dashboard');


// view engine setup
app.set('view engine', 'ejs' );

// STATIC FILES
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(cors())


// post contact route
app.use('/auth',authRouter );
app.use('/users',userRouter );
app.use('/contact',contactRouter );
// app.use('/dashboard',dashboardRouter );


// FOR PRODUCTION
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
   console.log(`Listening on port 8080`)
})
```

Comment: That "app crashed" line from your logs tells us virtually nothing, The useful information is above that. Please [edit] your question to include all contiguous error and warning lines from above that.

Comment: Thank you, Chris. I have edited it accordingly.

Comment: Great, thanks! But there should be even more. Run `heroku logs` without `--tail`, or if you are using the web dashboard make sure to scroll back.